# Getting cold calls data set

Tags: data-request, nlp, uses-of-open-data

I am looking for cold calls data set for my research.

the data should be an audio file of recorded calls. ( sales calls ..)

Any idea where can I get such data?

Comment: What should be in the data set? Please read [this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question. You risk the chance it gets closed as 'unclear what you're asking'.